# Gradle Kotlin JS Plugin - Could not generate decorated class

Tags: kotlin, gradle, corda

The Kotlin JS Gradle plugin crashes an otherwise valid build and I'd like to figure out why/how to fix it.

Following this guide https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-project-setup.html I attempted to compile some Kotlin code down to Javascript, but as soon as I added the plugin to the Gradle build, it started failing as seen below.

The Plugin configuration change I made to the otherwise valid (working) gradle build file was adding this on the top:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js' version '1.4.0'
}

kotlin {
    js {
        nodejs { }
        browser { }
    }
}
```

The full project source code can be cloned from in case you are kind enough to try it out locally: https://github.com/petermetz/corda/tree/build/rpc-javascript-build-target
Once cloned, change directories to the `./client/rpc` dir and then run `../../gradlew build` to observe the error.

I tried with both OpenJDK 8 and 11, outcome is the same.

```sh
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/peter/a/blockchain/corda/client/rpc/build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js', version: '1.4.0']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js']
   > Could not create an instance of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJsProjectExtension.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJsProjectExtension.
         > Cannot inherit from final class
```

Stack strace:

```sh
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js', version: '1.4.0']
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.exceptionOccurred(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:253)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:235)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:151)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:49)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor$1.run(BuildScriptProcessor.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:187)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:107)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:187)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:693)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectAccessListener.evaluateProjectAndDiscoverTasks(DefaultProjectAccessListener.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectAccessListener.beforeResolvingProjectDependency(DefaultProjectAccessListener.java:30)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency.beforeResolved(DefaultProjectDependency.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.ProjectIvyDependencyDescriptorFactory.createDependencyDescriptor(ProjectIvyDependencyDescriptorFactory.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultDependencyDescriptorFactory.createDependencyDescriptor(DefaultDependencyDescriptorFactory.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadataBuilder.addDependencies(DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadataBuilder.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadataBuilder.addDependenciesAndExcludes(DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadataBuilder.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.local.model.DefaultLocalComponentMetadata$DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadata.realizeDependencies(DefaultLocalComponentMetadata.java:512)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.local.model.DefaultLocalComponentMetadata$DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadata.addDefinedExcludes(DefaultLocalComponentMetadata.java:469)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.local.model.DefaultLocalComponentMetadata$DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadata.getExcludes(DefaultLocalComponentMetadata.java:460)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.NodeState.computeNodeExclusions(NodeState.java:613)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.NodeState.computeModuleResolutionFilter(NodeState.java:603)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.NodeState.visitOutgoingDependencies(NodeState.java:250)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:180)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:142)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:175)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$7.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:612)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:603)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$600(DefaultConfiguration.java:139)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$6.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:583)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$SafeExclusiveLockImpl.withLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:245)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveExclusively(DefaultConfiguration.java:579)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:574)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:556)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.getProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryGetProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:171)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryGetProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
        at build_a59uffdke0ttuugei94gnr34t$_run_closure4.doCall(/home/peter/a/blockchain/corda/node/capsule/build.gradle:68)
        at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureSelf(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:587)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.task(DefaultProject.java:1244)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:33)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:134)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:162)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:83)
        at build_a59uffdke0ttuugei94gnr34t.run(/home/peter/a/blockchain/corda/node/capsule/build.gradle:44)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:227)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:232)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:49)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor$1.run(BuildScriptProcessor.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:187)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:107)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:187)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:693)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluationDependsOn(DefaultProject.java:773)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluationDependsOn(DefaultProject.java:765)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:33)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:134)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:162)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:83)
        at build_a64xzv1jme15xht1kamyg6stx.run(/home/peter/a/blockchain/corda/core-tests/build.gradle:15)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:227)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:232)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:49)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor$1.run(BuildScriptProcessor.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:187)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:107)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:189)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:227)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:187)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:693)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:141)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:36)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:64)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:55)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperatingFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperatingFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperatingFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperatingFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareProjects(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:198)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:138)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:60)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:189)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:57)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        *** SOME DELETED DUE TO 30K max length of the question ***
       ...
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.inspectClass(ClassInspector.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.visitGraph(ClassInspector.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.inspect(ClassInspector.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.AbstractClassGenerator.inspectType(AbstractClassGenerator.java:245)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:191)
        ... 302 more
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue when using the `js` target in a Kotlin Multi-platform project. For some reason, adding an explicit name to the target definition solved the problem for me: `js("js") { browser {} }`

Answer (score 1):

I checked the link you shared, and it seems you are working on a forked version of Corda/corda. It is a very complex repository that includes all code for the Corda core.

If you just want to implement a kotlin/JS for your webserver. I would actually suggest you start with the spring webserver samples we have at [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Basic/spring-webserver).

My guess is that the dependencies of the corda/corda rpc client project might be all the way on the project root level. That is why you will have dependencies issues when you try to compile it in the subdirectory client folder.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I appreciate the advice. Indeed I am working with a fork of Corda. Unfortunately using spring or anything JVM/graalVM based would defeat the purpose: I'm trying to have JS bindings so that I don't have to manage an external process from my NodeJS process (makes things much harder for containerization and just in general for the maintenance of the code).